# google chrome command line options

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

When I run some chrome app such as...

`google-chrome -app=chrome-extension://kjebfhglflhjjjiceimfkgicifkhjlnm/index.html`

...it always starts two windows, one in app mode, and another in the usual window.

I'd like the application to only start in app mode.  What is the (or is there a) command line option to accomplish this?

Comment: What about running google chrome extensions through chrome interface?

Comment: @IshikawaYoshi thanks,but in some circumstance,I prefer command line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an -app-id argument for starting up with extensions.

```
google-chrome -app-id=kjebfhglflhjjjiceimfkgicifkhjlnm
```

Should do the trick.